# JqueryMobile Splash page for non-mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, android, jquery-mobile

I´m using jquerymobile to build a simple mobile app and would like to know, whats the best way one should use to make a index page for non-mobile browsers when visiting the mobile app adress ?

I use index.html for now, and i can access it with any desktop browser, but i would want to restrict it to mobile only, and show a different page for desktop browsers.

Which approuch would be better?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your index.html page you can include some detection script that detects the type of browser (it may be easier to use a whitelist of mobile devices rather then a blacklist of desktop browsers) and then redirects desktop browsers to something like index_desktop.html.

Sorry if the answer isn't as exact as you would have liked but I generally allow desktop browsers the ability to view my mobile pages (I just make sure there is a "View Desktop Version" link somewhere on the page.

Comment: Thanks Jasper, in this case i would like the url to redirect if desktop, so it can show some instructions to use in mobile. Thanks

Comment: You can whitelist iPhone and Android with js code like this: if (!navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) && !navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) {window.location = 'index_desktop.html';}. You would have to look-up a more complete list of mobile devices to make sure and allow all of them access to your mobile site.